# Weird shader behavior in Stage3d

Tags: actionscript-3, shader, stage3d

I am using this Vertex Shader on Stage3d:

```
<script id="per-fragment-lighting-vs2" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
    attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;
    attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

    uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
    uniform mat3 uNMatrix;

    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
    varying vec3 vTransformedNormal;
    varying vec4 vPosition;


    void main(void) {
        vPosition = uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
        gl_Position = uPMatrix * vPosition;
        vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
        vTransformedNormal = uNMatrix * aVertexNormal;
    }
</script>
```

With this result:

[image]

If I edit the shader like this:

```
<script id="per-fragment-lighting-vs2" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
    attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;
    attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

    uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
    uniform mat3 uNMatrix;

    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
    varying vec3 vTransformedNormal;
    varying vec4 vPosition;


    void main(void) {
        **gl_Position = uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);**
        vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
        vTransformedNormal = uNMatrix * aVertexNormal;
    }
</script>
```

And premultiply the perspective in actionscript I get a correct UV display, although it has a different perspective, it looks ok.

[image]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have reversed the matrix multiply sequence in your first shader implementation, so you should first multiply by perspective, and then by MV.

```
    void main(void) {
        vPosition = uPMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
        gl_Position = uMVMatrix * vPosition;
        vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
        vTransformedNormal = uNMatrix * aVertexNormal;
   }
```

Comment: Hi @Vesper. The shader works awesomely on WebGL http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=1658 , maybe there's something wrong on my flash classes. I tried changing your vars but doesn't work. Thanks though!